# only Scrolling programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I don't know if this makes sense at all. I have `UIScrollView` from interface builder hooked it up as an outlet on top of my `UIScrollView` I have a `UIImage` view which holds an image called Scroll Background it is an extra half in screen real estate - my app is landscape and the image is an about half the screen taller. The image is hooked up as an outlet too. I have a button on a toolbar that brings up the keyboard when the button is pressed I'd like to programmatically scroll to the bottom of the `UIImage` view and when it is resigned I'd like to programmatically scroll to the top. I don't want the user to be able to scroll just for the app to scroll programmatically.

I can't seem to get this method to work and I'm not sure why :/

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see exactly where and how you're using `-scrollRectToVisible:animated:`.

Answer (score 1):

`scrollRectToVisible:animated:` is a non-intuative method to use in my opinion. In order to accomplish what you are after you should be able to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on the `UIScrollView` that will prevent users from scrolling.

Then in order to scroll the view programmatically you can call scrollRectToVisible but you need to give it a `CGRect` that is representative of the area you want to show. So in your case to scroll to the top:

```
CGRect visibleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) , CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));

[self.myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:visibleFrame animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps!